# google-mock ppa

Tags: ppa

I am looking for an up to date version of google-mocks since 1.4 is no longer supported and has a [show stopper bug](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/issues/detail?id=147) using ICC.  So, does anyone know of a PPA?  My google search skills did not show anything.

Comment: I haven't found any ppa but; [Oneric will be have 1.6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=google-mock) in its repositories. You will also find deb's [here](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/google-mock/); but they might not work due to your bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent found a PPA with this in - however Oneiric has v1.6 in its repositories.

The dependencies are:

```
libc6 (>= 2.1.3) libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) libgtest-dev (>= 1.6.0) libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0) python
```

As far as I can gather - and assuming you are using 11.04 - most of the dependencies are satisfied by the versions in the 11.04 repositories.

Therefore you should be able to download the .deb file from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/google-mock)

libgtest-dev is older in natty - you should also download and install this from the [oneiric area of launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/libgtest-dev) before installing the google-mock deb

N.B. download either 32bit or 64bit as appropriate to your platform and install with the syntax

```
sudo dpkg -i [package name].deb
```

As always - ensure you have a good backup you can reuse if your system becomes unstable.